# Visual Studio 2019 IDE Performance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on my Laptop that is connected to an external monitor. Both my laptop and the external monitor have a 4k resolution.

I'm facing a weird performance issue, where after every click/right-click the whole UI freezes for a couple of seconds. For eg. if I right click on a project, the UI completely freezes, not even the mouse moves and after 1-2 seconds I see the context menu.

My laptop is new and this happens only with VS 2019 and only when my laptop is connected to an external 4k monitor.

Anyone else faced a similar problem or knows a solution for this?

My Laptop has the following configuration:

- Intel i7-10750H 2.60GHz
- 16GB RAM
- SK Hynix PC601 M.2 SSD
- GTX 1650 Ti Graphics Card

Comment: If the mouse doesn't move then the problem is not with the Visual Studio, but somewhere else. Maybe video drivers.

Comment: But it only happens in case of Visual Studio. All other software that I've used don't seem to have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging, I found these options in Visual Studio. Turning them off seemed to do the trick:

`Tools` > `Options` and then under `Environment` > `General` **deselect** the following options:

- Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance

  - Use hardware graphics acceleration if available

If you want to go one step further, you could also disable the following option along with those above. (but in my case, just disabling those two seemed to suffice)

- Enable rich client visual experience

Here's the GPU usage before and after disabling the options (for similar UI inputs).

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In the *Before* picture, the duration for which the GPU 3D usage remained consistently high is when the UI froze.

What I still don't seem to understand is why VS would need so much of GPU 3D computational power.

Comment: The whole 2D rendering nowadays typically also uses the 3D pipeline (i.e. for scaling fonts). Specific 2D hardware optimizations are mostly history.  If disabling hardware acceleration helps, this does point to a problem with your driver.